# Cookie names cannot contain any of the following

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I am sorry for my English. I use Google translate.

I have a question for php. Namely work with CURL.

When you try to bring COOKIE error:

```
Warning: Cookie names can not contain any of the following '= ,; \ t \ r \ n \ 013 \ 014 'in /var/www/test2.lo/app/mvc/controllers/index.php on line 62
```

My code:

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
```

Deciding to check that the variable I did the following:

```
var_dump ($cookies);
```

I was surprised. but I received a string (37) "user_id = 61294582; sid = 6079823296354752"

What kind of mistake? How to fix it?

Comment: `var_dump ($ cookies);` theres a space between `$` and `cookies`

Comment: @phplover This is a bug Google translator. he automatically put space.

Comment: actually its `$_COOKIE`

Answer (score 6):

The actual name of the cookie object cannot have any of those characters in it.

Example:

cookie name

cookie=name

cookie;name

cookie,name

These are all bad and will give you an error.

Please remove any spaces, carriage returns, and non-printing characters, as well as any equal sign, comma, or semi-colon.

Comment: thank you. As I realized the problem was that $cookies were the characters are not visible in the browser, and that has got me stumped. After removing all illegal characters everything works fine

Comment: @Dokuro : If Psychrom has solved your problem, be sure to accept the answer by using the check-mark near the up and down arrows near the top left of the answer. Doing so will give "valuable" reputation points and gives readers an incentive to keep answering questions. Good luck to all.